# Where is erlang-start on Erlang R17 in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, erlang

I have emacs running on Mac OS X to work on a Erlang project. I have followed the instructions at http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/erlang_mode_chapter.html to configure "erlang mode" but I can't locate erlang-start. I've completed this on Windows, just can't seem to find the right config for Mac OS X.

Erlang is installed from the R17 package for Mac OS from Erlang Solutions. The files are installed to /usr/local/lib/erlang but I can't find erlang-start.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Erlang/OTP 17.0 installed to `/usr/local` you should be able to find `erlang-start.el` here:

```
/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/tools-2.6.14/emacs/erlang-start.el
```

Answer (score 0):

The file `erlang-start.el` should come with the installation of Erlang. You can try to locate it by issuing the command `locate erlang-start.el` or search for the file using Finder. (Unfortunately, I don't know the normal installation location.)